# Add percent to boxes of image after prediction?

Tags: darknet

I'm working with darknet and want to add the prediction in percent next to the label with darknet like this:

[image]

rather than the default like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this? after you've run darknet it displays the probability that the label surrounding the object is the actual label. This is what i want to add to the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to add it. I've added the code for anyone with the same question in the future so it's copy and paste. remember to re-make darknet afterwards.

We need to replace draw_directions function in darknet/src/image.c with the following:

```c
    void draw_detections(image im, detection *dets, int num, float thresh, char **names, image **alphabet, int classes)
    {
        int i,j;
    
        for(i = 0; i < num; ++i){
            char labelstr[4096] = {0};
            int class = -1;
            for(j = 0; j < classes; ++j){
                if (dets[i].prob[j] > thresh){
                    if (class < 0) { 
                        /* this line adds the percent to the image*/
                        sprintf(labelstr,"%s %f%%",names[j], (dets[i].prob[j]*100) ); 
                        class = j;
                    } else {
                        strcat(labelstr, ", ");
                        strcat(labelstr, names[j]);
                    }
                    printf("%s: %.0f%%\n", names[j], dets[i].prob[j]*100);
                }
            }
            if(class >= 0){
                int width = im.h * .006;
    
                /*
                   if(0){
                   width = pow(prob, 1./2.)*10+1;
                   alphabet = 0;
                   }
                 */
    
                //printf("%d %s: %.0f%%\n", i, names[class], prob*100);
                int offset = class*123457 % classes;
                float red = get_color(2,offset,classes);
                float green = get_color(1,offset,classes);
                float blue = get_color(0,offset,classes);
                float rgb[3];
    
                //width = prob*20+2;
    
                rgb[0] = red;
                rgb[1] = green;
                rgb[2] = blue;
                box b = dets[i].bbox;
                //printf("%f %f %f %f\n", b.x, b.y, b.w, b.h);
    
                int left  = (b.x-b.w/2.)*im.w;
                int right = (b.x+b.w/2.)*im.w;
                int top   = (b.y-b.h/2.)*im.h;
                int bot   = (b.y+b.h/2.)*im.h;
    
                if(left < 0) left = 0;
                if(right > im.w-1) right = im.w-1;
                if(top < 0) top = 0;
                if(bot > im.h-1) bot = im.h-1;
    
                draw_box_width(im, left, top, right, bot, width, red, green, blue);
                if (alphabet) {
                    image label = get_label(alphabet, labelstr, (im.h*.03));
                    draw_label(im, top + width, left, label, rgb);
                    free_image(label);
                }
                if (dets[i].mask){
                    image mask = float_to_image(14, 14, 1, dets[i].mask);
                    image resized_mask = resize_image(mask, b.w*im.w, b.h*im.h);
                    image tmask = threshold_image(resized_mask, .5);
                    embed_image(tmask, im, left, top);
                    free_image(mask);
                    free_image(resized_mask);
                    free_image(tmask);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).